# Play video and game in same scene in cocos2dx

Tags: android, video, cocos2d-x

COCOS2dX masters ,I just started game development with COCOS2dX and stuck at some point.

I am developing a simplegame by learning from sample provided by cocos2dx development kit.Every thing is working good.

**Game requirements:**

1. Game has single screen.
2. screen will divided into to parts.
3. 40% of screen will use to play video clips.
4. 60% of screen will use for play the game.

**What I have done with is:**

1. Game is working and uses whole screen.
2. Able to play video it also uses whole screen.

**What I have to achieve :**

1. Video should be plays continuously in 40% of screen
2. Remaining part should be use for playing game.

In short I need to perform both the functionality in single "CCScene"

Thanks in advance for best solution.

Comment: how do you play your video, through which API? If you are using AV apis from Apple SDK, the video window would likely overlay the screen on top of your root scene cocos window, depending on your setup. One way would be to manage to play the video inside a specific CCLayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by changing the Cocos2dxActivity class in libcocos2dx a bit, to add the VideoView there.

First of all, add this xml layout to res/layout in libcocos2dx :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout will be the new layout for your app.

Secondly you have to change the `init()` method in Cocos2dxActivity to this:

```
public void init() {

    // Set our new layout as the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    // FrameLayout
    //ViewGroup.LayoutParams framelayout_params =
    //new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    //ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    //FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    //framelayout.setLayoutParams(framelayout_params);

    Resources res = this.getResources();
    int id = res.getIdentifier("YOUR_VIDEO_NAME_HERE", "raw", getPackageName());

    if (id == 0) {
        Log.e("Cocos2dx VIDEO", "ERROR! Resource id == 0");
        Log.e("Cocos2dx VIDEO", "ERROR! Check name of video!");
    } else {

        VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(vv);
        vv.setMediaController(mc);
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + id));
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mp != null)
                    mp.setLooping(true);
            });

        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.start();
    }

    FrameLayout framelayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    // Cocos2dxEditText layout
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams edittext_layout_params =
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Cocos2dxEditText edittext = new Cocos2dxEditText(this);
    edittext.setLayoutParams(edittext_layout_params);

    // ...add to FrameLayout
    framelayout.addView(edittext);

    // Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView
    this.mGLSurfaceView = this.onCreateView();

    // ...add to FrameLayout
    framelayout.addView(this.mGLSurfaceView);

    // Switch to supported OpenGL (ARGB888) mode on emulator
    if (isAndroidEmulator())
       this.mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

    this.mGLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());
    this.mGLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxEditText(edittext);

    //// Set framelayout as the content view
    //setContentView(framelayout);
}
```

This will give you a VideView covering 40% on the left of the screen and your cocos gameplay area covering 60% on the right.

You should place your videos in res/raw folder in YOUR project.

Also, this is Android-only solution (based on the tag you provided in the question). To achieve this on iOS or other platforms you'd have to make other changes in cocos library code for these platforms.

Edit : Remeber to clean (just to be safe) and rebuild the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two CCLayers in your CCScene, one layer will play the Video and the other will play the game !

Comment: Yes, I know that but need kind of example if you have

Comment: How to divide screen in 60-40 ratio?

Comment: If you set the design resolution to say 480 * 800, and assuming the app is portrait, 60 percent will be 480 pixels. set the layer sizes accordingly. There is a CCSlidingLayer code available on cocos2dx forums which lets you set content size, that may help you if CCLayer does not work out.